# Google teachable machine model loading problem in python coded project

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, vision

**Context:**

```
 1. python==3.6.6 
 2. Keras==2.2.4
 3. tensorflow==2.1.0
 4. pillow==7.0.0
```

When I load the model trained in Google Teachable Machine, it show me the following error code.

**Code of loading model program:**

```
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('keras_model.h5')

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('38.jpg')

#resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
#resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# display the resized image
image.show()

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

**Error message:**

```
"/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/bin/python" "/home/muhammad_abdullah/PycharmProjects/google teachable machine/main.py"
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/PycharmProjects/google teachable machine/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('keras_model.h5')
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 146, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 212, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 89, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 192, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 352, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 89, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 192, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 352, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 89, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 192, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1121, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1105, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 89, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 194, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 446, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/home/muhammad_abdullah/anaconda3/envs/google teachable machine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 80, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', kwargs.keys())
ValueError: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['ragged']))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important line is towards the bottom where it mentions `ragged`.

This happens for me when I use a new Keras model in an old version of Keras.  How did you generate the model?  My bet is that you used a newer version of TensorFlow to build it.

The best and easiest thing to do is rebuild the .h5 Keras model using the same version of TF you are using.  However, you can also export the model as .json, modify the input layer and then reload in the older version.  However be warned that a couple other changes happened that you will run into after that.